# Ext JS 5/Sencha CMD : How to run Ext JS app in tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, extjs, sencha-cmd

I want to test my app from tomcat server, so I put my application ext js in my webapp folder and I wrote the correct path of my index.html in the web.xml file. I also modified my app.json like this :

```
"js": [
    {
        "path": "/application/app.js",
        "bundle": true
    }
],

"css": [
    { 
        "path": "/application/bootstrap.css",
        "bootstrap": true
    }
],
```

Now the app.js is load correctly but I have this message from firebug console when I start my app :

TypeError: Ext.onReady is not a function.

I think the ext js framework is not load but I don't know why. Should I change any configuration file ?
I use sencha cmd to build my app.

**Edit 1** : The network console

[image]

**Edit 2** : Here is my directory tree

Application directory is in webapp directory.

[image]

My welcome-file-list conf. in my web.xml file :

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>application/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**Edit 3** : 
before starting my server, I run "sencha app build" command.

Here is his log :

```
Sencha Cmd v5.0.1.231[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : default
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[INF] Writing content to D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application/bootstrap.js
[INF] Writing content to D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application/bootstrap.json
[WRN] C1014: callParent has no target (this.callParent in Ext.form.field.Picker.onOtherFocus) -- D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application\ext\src\form\field\Picker.js:325
[WRN] C1014: callParent has no target (me.callParent in Ext.form.field.Tag.mimicBlur) -- D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application\ext\src\form\field\Tag.js:1298
[WRN] C1014: callParent has no target (me.callParent in Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing.startEditByClick) -- D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application\ext\src\grid\plugin\RowEditing.js:278
[WRN] C1014: callParent has no target (this.callParent in Ext.rtl.selection.CellModel.doMove) -- D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application\ext\src\rtl\selection\CellModel.js:12
[WRN] C1014: callParent has no target (this.callParent in Ext.rtl.selection.TreeModel.onKeyLeft) -- D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application\ext\src\rtl\selection\TreeModel.js:16
[WRN] C1014: callParent has no target (this.callParent in Ext.rtl.selection.TreeModel.onKeyRight) -- D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application\ext\src\rtl\selection\TreeModel.js:8
[WRN] C1014: callParent has no target (this.callParent in Ext.ux.TabCloseMenu.onBeforeDestroy) -- D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application\ext\src\ux\TabCloseMenu.js:83
[INF] Compressing data with YuiJavascriptCompressor
[INF] Concatenating output to file D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application\build\production\Eloi\app.js
[INF] merging resources into D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application\build\production\Eloi\resources
[INF] merged 0 resources into D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application\build\production\Eloi\resources
[INF] merging resources into D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application\build\production\Eloi\resources
[INF] merged 0 resources into D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application\build\production\Eloi\resources
[INF] writing sass content to D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application/build/temp/production/Eloi/sass/Eloi-all.scss.tmp
[INF] appending sass content to D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application/build/temp/production/Eloi/sass/Eloi-all.scss.tmp
[INF] appending sass content to D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application/build/temp/production/Eloi/sass/Eloi-all.scss.tmp
[INF] executing compass using system installed ruby runtime
unchanged Eloi-all.scss
[INF] writing sass content to D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application/build/temp/production/Eloi/slicer-temp/Eloi-example.scss.tmp
[INF] executing compass using system installed ruby runtime
unchanged Eloi-example.scss
[INF] Writing content to D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application/sass/example/bootstrap.json
[INF] Writing content to D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application/sass/example/bootstrap.js
[INF] Capturing theme image
[INF] Capture complete
[INF] Slicing images...
[INF] Slicing complete - generated 320 images
[INF] Copying page resources to D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application\build\production\Eloi
[INF] Generating file deltas to D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application/build/production/Eloi/deltas
[INF] Writing content to D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application/build/production/Eloi/app.json
[INF] Writing content to D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application/build/production/Eloi/microloader.js
[INF] Appending content to D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application/build/production/Eloi/microloader.js
[INF] Building output markup to D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application/build/production/Eloi/index.html
[INF] Writing content to D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application/build/production/Eloi/index.html
[INF] generating cache manifest to D:\eclipse-workspace\Eloi_extJS\eloi-web\src\main\webapp\application/build/production/Eloi/cache.appcache
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution. In fact sencha cmd 5.0.1.231 does not work. It needs to be updated to Version 5.0.1.250 (beta) and it works.

For it work you must run these commands :

```
sencha app upgrade
sencha app build
```

Don't forget to restart cmd on Windows otherwise the cmd always points to the old version of sencha.